# SVN relaltive path externals

Tags: php, svn, version-control, repository, versioning

I have a repository of tools I have written in php and a repository of application code which will use them.  I want the two folders to end up on the same level when I check them out.  I tried to accomplish this by setting the svn:externals property for the application folder to

```
../toolkit http://(toolkit repo url)/
```

but apparently it can't do this with relative paths.  I do not want the toolkit folder to be inside the application folder, I want them on the same level but doing

```
toolkit http://(toolkit repo url)/
```

will put the toolkit inside the application folder. Anyone know how I can do what I am trying to do here? (If it matters, I am doing this from the command line not tortise svn or some other program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to achieve the following folder structure after adding the `svn:externals` property:

> ```
> C:\SvnCheckouts\MyApplication\
>                               src\
>                               toolkit\
> ```

... with `toolkit\` being added as a result of the external. In that case, you should add the external to the `MyApplication\` folder.

If you're trying instead to add the external to the `src\` folder, then you're out of luck because, although the following is a valid external definition ...

> `http://(toolkit repo url)/  ..\toolkit`

... SVN will strip the slash and create a folder within `src\` named `..toolkit` (notice that I've placed the URL before the name of the intended external folder, as per best practice).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found that what I am trying to do is perfectly legal in SVN 1.6 but I was trying to do it in SVN 1.4 so all I have to do is upgrade to the newer version.

Comment: actually it still may not be... I think it is only in the url part that relative paths with '..' can be used

Comment: That is correct. If SVN allowed relative paths for the second parameter (the target folder), which navigate up out of the SVN checkout folder you are setting the `svn:externals` on, then it would be problematic because you could conceivably have it resolve to a path totally outside of your checkout, which SVN can't track.

Comment: ok fair enough.  I think I will write my own custom checkout script to put things exactly where I want them rather than try to externals to do it for me.  Externals just seemed more self contained.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that your script will checkout from multiple locations, so if you make a change to, say, your application code as well as your toolkit, then you'll need to perform two commits, one for each checkout.